# how to send a TCP FIN using python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I was looking at how to send a TCP FIN using python socket.

I tried using the socket.socket.close and it sends out a TCP RST and not a TCP FIN. Can someone please let me know what is the API?

Comment: You can inadvertently generate an RST instead of a FIN when closing a socket if there is data that has been received into the socket receive buffer but not yet read by your application.

Answer (score 4):

From the python doc:

> Note
>
> close() releases the resource associated with a connection but does
>   not necessarily close the connection immediately. If you want to close
>   the connection in a timely fashion, call shutdown() before close().

Comment: I tried the close() but it sends out the TCP RST instead of TCP FIN.

Comment: I tried the shutdown(1) and it sent out a TCP with FIN bit set

Comment: I wonder if the Python documentation is accurate. It's hard to see how closing the socket wouldn't be equally 'timely'.